# Colorizing specific window tabs in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Is there a simple extension that would allow me to colorize these window tabs? I find myself spending a second or two getting to the right tab, especially when they're in a different order between machines. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried another theme?  You might not be able to make them different colors, but you might be able to find, a theme that makes stand out from one another.